# Will durable function automatically create the storage shares, queues and containers it needs?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I deployed an azure durable function to azure using visual studio.
It created a storage account that contains quite a few shares, queues and containers.

I am exporting the ARM templates to automate deployment via DevOps.
On exporting the ARM template for the storage account that was created, it contains definitions for all these shares, queues & containers.

If I remove these, will the function, or the zip deployment step of the deployment pipeline create what it needs in the storage when its run?

Answer (score 1):

***AFAIK, Whenever we are exporting template from Azure portal we need to customize the required things as the resource is already exist in our resource group and portal itself***.

*So When we are using zip deployment for durable function or directly deploy them from local in storage account there will be shares, blobs and table will create automatically for storing the data into them*.

*Once we export and re-deploy according to our requirement the deployment will be succeed then we need to zip deploy our function to it (e.g: Durable function, http trigger etc.)* .

***SCREENSHOT FOR REFERENCE:-***
[image]

[image]

*For more information regarding exporting templates please refer the below links:-*

- ***MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION***| [**Use exported template from the Azure portal**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjvWF.png) & [***Integrate ARM templates with Azure Pipelines***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/add-template-to-azure-pipelines)
- ***GitHub***| [**Issue with deploying Durable function to Azure using ARM Template**](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1537) .